# Vue 3 datatable plugin how to add action buttons?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, datatables, inertiajs

I am using vue3 and laravel inertia for this project. How do I add a custom action button in the last column? Currently I tried by doing and the `handleUser()` function isnt working or triggering, i got only a `console.log` there.

[jquery datatables for vue 3](https://datatables.net/blog/2022-06-22-vue#Extensions-example)

```
const { users } = defineProps({
    users: Object
})

const usersData = computed(() => {
    return toRaw(users).map(user => {
        return [
            user.id_number,
            user.name,
            user.email,
            user.course.name,
            user.school_year,
            user.subject_code,
            user.phone_number,
            user.is_active ? `<span class="badge rounded-pill text-bg-primary">Approved</span>` : `<span class="badge rounded-pill text-bg-danger">Pending</span>`,
           `<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @click="handleUser(user)">Approve</button>`
        ];
    });
})
```

My datatable component

```
                        <DataTable :data="usersData" class="display" ref="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Id Number</th>
                                    <th>Student Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Program</th>
                                    <th>School Year</th>
                                    <th>Subject Code</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </DataTable>
```

my table display
[image]

Maybe did something wrong by converting the user props to usersData? since its reactive I cant display the `users` to the datatable so I converted it.